# wrapping absolute divs doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want my #wrap to have **bottom:0** so that **my cards all align to the bottom of the viewport** but it doesn't seem work when I applied position absolute to the wrapper. Why does it so?

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="card" id="card1">black</div>
<div class="card" id="card2">pink</div>
<div class="card" id="card3">orange</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#wrap{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height: 100% !important;
min-height: 100% !important;
}

#card1{
    background:black;
    top:0;
}

#card2{
    background:pink;
    top:10px;
}

#card3{
    background:orange;
    top:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t94vdwak/1/

Comment: @MrLister added a fiddle

Comment: @AaronMusktin do you want them to be on the bottom of the viewport even if you scroll down?

Comment: Without scrollbars and with padding @AaronMusktin http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/rrapj20o/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go buddy

http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/rrapj20o/4/

```
.card{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#wrap{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 120px;
    min-height: 120px;
}

#card1{
    background:black;
    top:0;
}

#card2{
    background:pink;
    top:10px;
}

#card3{
    background:orange;
    top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper itself must be positioned absolutely at the bottom and then the cards must be offset within the wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryvvyqfc/

```
.card {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#wrap{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

#card1{
    background:black;
    top:0;
}

#card2{
    background:pink;
    top:10px;
}

#card3{
    background:orange;
    top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you specify that you need the stack of cards on the bottom of the viewport, well `position: absolute` align items against the page, if you want to align items against the viewport you could use `position: fixed`.

Here I edited your sample:

```css
.card{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:120px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
#wrap{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: visible;
}
#card1{
    background:black;
    bottom:20px;
}
#card2{
    background:pink;
    bottom:10px;
}
#card3{
    background:orange;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="card" id="card1">black</div>
    <div class="card" id="card2">pink</div>
    <div class="card" id="card3">orange</div>
</div>
```

This way your items will stick to the bottom of the viewport even if you scroll down.

How it works is that wrapper has no height but it does not hide the overflow and cards are positioned not from the top(like in your example) but from the bottom (reverse of what you did)

Don't forget that if you want the items to be over other content to adjust `z-index` property.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 He specified that he needs to position elements at the bottom of the viewport, `position: absolute` does not do that. As you can see in this [reference](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 You have to understand that 1. User that asks the question is the one that decides what solution is useful for him/her 2. Your behavior seems highly inappropriate and completely not in the spirit of stack overflow, [reference how to be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: how to apply margin: 0 20px?

Comment: @AaronMusktin to which element you would like to add it? Or what would you like to archive with the margins?